# Grothendieck group of intersection of quadrics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

Conjecturally, for a complete intersection $X$ the group $K_0(X)$ is finitely generated iff $H^{p,q}(X)=0$ for $p≠q$. This holds if and only if $X$ is a quadric, a cubic surface, or an even-dimensional intersection of 2 quadrics (see M. Rapoport, Complément à l'article de P. Deligne "La conjecture de Weil pour les surfaces K3", Inv. math. 15 (1972), 227-236). But Orlov proved that a intersection of two even-dimensional quadrics admits a semiorthogonal decomposition $D^b(X)=\langle \mathcal{O}_X(-d+3),...,\mathcal{O}_X,D^b(C)\rangle$, where $d$ is the dimension of $X$ and $C$ is a hyperelliptic curve. Since $K_0(C)$ is a direct summand of $K_0(X)$ this is not finitely generated in general. Furthermore $D^b(X)$ does not admit a tilting bundle...

Comment: What is the question??

Comment: The decomposition you mention is due to Bondal and Orlov, not just Orlov.

Comment: I personally don't see any problem here. As far as I'm concerned, an intersection of two even-dimensional quadrics has odd dimension.

Comment: I apologize, thats right...the decomposition is due to Bondal and Orlov.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but if for these intersections of two quadrics $H^{q,p}(X)=0$ and $K_0(X)$ is not finitaly generated then the sbove conjecture is wrong...

Comment: The intersection of two quadric surfaces is an elliptic curve, which has $H^{1,0}$ nontrivial. I believe higher-dimensional cases are similar, with $H^{n,n-1}$.

Comment: It seems like you are interested in complete intersections of hodge level $0$, for which the relevant intersection of two quadrics has *even* dimension. Intersections of two quadrics of *odd* dimension behave quite differently (e.g. elliptic curves), as these have hodge level $1$.

Comment: But these intersections of Hodge level zero would also not have finitely generated Grothendieck group...